# SynEdit - where to find community?

Tags: delphi, synedit

I'm looking for some forum/mailing list where can I find active SynEdit users community? Official forums on SourceForge looks like dead...

Comment: Why not ask some SynEdit questions here, and maybe you will attract some active members? :)

Comment: I'm here too. I've been using it and obtain the unicode port of the web, but I'm not an expert - yet!
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Unicode SynEdit](http://mh-nexus.de/en/unisynedit.php), This is the Unicode version of SynEdit. the forum is active http://forum.mh-nexus.de/

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Try also [SynEdit/Bugs](http://sourceforge.net/p/synedit/bugs/): this forum is relatively active.